# Hosting a Django app on a Windows machine

Tags: python, django, web-deployment, msdeploy, web-development-server

I've developed a **django** web application which I now want to deploy so that everyone in my organization can start accessing the website. However, I do not have a dedicated server location to actually host it. I have been given a dedicated **Windows** machine to host the app on. Previously I've always used things like Heroku or AWS to deploy websites which make it really easy, so I really have no idea how to turn a desktop into a server hosting a web application. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to do this using free software?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with IIS module of Windows.
I applied the following tutorials on my company's intranet and it works:
https://medium.com/@Jonny_Waffles/deploy-django-on-iis-def658beae92

Comment: The resource in this answer requires the use of wfastcgi.  But according to this Microsoft article, the wfastcgi project is no longer maintained and is not recommended for use.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/configure-web-apps-for-iis-windows?view=vs-2019